# mod_rewrite leads to 404

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect (internally) `example.com/snippets/_filename_` to `example.com/snippets/?f=_filename_` using `mod_rewrite`... And it is not working.

The contents of my .htaccess file, which is placed inside of the `snippets` directory are:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^snippets/([^/\.]+)$ /snippets/?f=$1 [L]
```

This doesn't seem to work on my Apache 2.4 server, and instead causes a 404 error.

**UPDATE**

What my .htaccess looks like now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule snippets/(.*)$ /snippets/index.php?f=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Maybe setting a base? RewriteBase /

Comment: Sadly, no. It's [still not working](https://uploads.hussain.cf/snippets/ex.js).

Comment: OK i see, can you try to redirect to an actual file? like example.com/snippets/index.php?f=$1 just to see if it works?

Comment: @Eric oh, use fibonacci.js

Comment: you have to redirect to a physical file

Comment: @Eric oh okay user what you mean

Comment: post what you have now (htaccess)

Comment: try RewriteRule ^(snippets)/(.*)$ snippets/index.php?f=$1 [L] and the snippets folder has to be on root

Comment: @Eric not working either, perhaps because I am using CloudFlare?